# Map Function on Spark returning 'NoneType'

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have written the following code in Python to run on Apache Spark:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

def generate_kdmer(seq):
    res = []
    beg2, end2 = k+d, k+d+k
    last = len(seq) - end2 + 1
    for i in range(last):
        res.append([seq[i:i+k], seq[i+beg2:i+end2]])
    return res.sort()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("Usage: kdmer <file> <k> <d>, file=sys.stderr")
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="KDmerGenerator")
    k, d = int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3])
    lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
    kdmer = lines.map(generate_kdmer).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
    output = kdmer.collect()
    for i in output:
        print(str(i[0]) + ' | ' + str(i[1]))
    sc.stop()
```

It generates the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType
```

The generate_kdmer function is supposed to return a list, and the lists returned by the map would be appended together into one in reduce, but I have no idea why it keeps returning 'None'. I have tried to print something inside the function, but it showed nothing on the console, is this function really being executed? Is there a better way of passing a function to map on Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `res.sort()` returns a `NoneType`. You want to do the sort and then return the `res`

```
res.sort()
return res
```

You can plug this directly into [python fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/) to see what I'm talking about:

```
k = 1
d = 1
seq = "This is a string"
res = []
beg2, end2 = k+d, k+d+k
last = len(seq) - end2 + 1
for i in range(last):
  res.append([seq[i:i+k], seq[i+beg2:i+end2]])
print(res.sort())
print(res)
```